# Repeated system restart

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, software-center, reboot, gpu-driver

Since I changed my HW I got a lot of problems with my PC.

I changed my 10yrs old PC because I couldn't upgrade my Ubuntu 12.04 due to the video board not beeing supported.

I bought the following components

- Processor :  AMD Athlon 5150 4 core s 1,6 GHz AM1
- Motherboard: Asus AM1M-A Micro ATX
- Memory:  2×4Gb Kingston KVR16N11S8/4 4GB 1Rx8 512M x 64-Bit PC3-12800 CL11 240-Pin DIMM RAM DDR3 1600MHz
- Power: Corsair CP-9020101-EU CX Series CX450M ATX/EPS Modulaire 80 Plus Bronze 450W
- HDD:  Seagate ST2000DM001 2Tb 3.5 Serial ATA

In the beginng I used my old HDD with Ubuntu 12.04 and it was working fine but as soon as I did the upgrade to 14.04 I got problems:
the system never stop to reboot or show the login window and when I login (correct account name and pwd) after a while it comes back to the login window.
I tried to do a new fresh installation of 16.04 and the problem is still the same.

Then I did a parallel installation of windows 7, the default OS is Ubuntu but once I select Ubuntu, the system does the boot but end with a system restart. If I let the system continue, after around 10 restart the system succeeds to open Ubuntu but the problem don't stop there!

In Ubuntu I can't open the software center , each time I open it , it's crashing.

I've read on the web (but I can't remember where) that the video card that is embedded in AM1M motherboard is not supported by Ubuntu.

If this can fix the problem I'm keen to purchase a new video card, but I would like to be sure that is supported by Ubuntu.

Comment: And what is the video card? I see everything else only ))

Comment: @Pilot6 All I can find is that the On-board video is  produced by the processor so Athlon™ 5150 APU with Radeon™ R3 Series would seem to be correct. Perhaps the output of `sudo lshw -C display` [edit]ed into the post would help us help you!

Comment: *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Kabini [Radeon HD 8400 / R3 Series]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:44 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d07fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:feb00000-feb3ffff memory:feb40000-feb5ffff

Comment: It is the 2nd day the system is booting normally ...even if I don't understand why it is behaving normally ,I cross the fingers  :-)   

I have found in /etc/fstab 
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=5fd7dee6-7eeb-4d54-b77e-45fec647e3be /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=c85e627f-d215-4cae-84ee-8d992fa7caa9 none            swap    sw              0       0
maybe the different HD connection play a role ?

Comment: I'm still in trouble. The PC takes around 40mn rebooting continuously to get in Ubuntu. If I choose Win 7 it start w/o problem. Any suggestion is welcomed !!!